# WebSphere, sendRedirect and HTTPS

Tags: redirect, https, websphere

Environment: WebSphere App Server / WebSphere Portal 7, fronted by IBM IHS/Apache httpd using was_ap20_module / mod_was_ap20_http.

I have a servlet or JSP page with a redirect like

```
response.sendRedirect("/wps/myportal/....")
```

The generated HTTP ends up with the right host and port for the IHS/Apache endpoint but the wrong protocol.  It is http instead of https.

For example, if IHS/Apache is listening on `https://myserver.com` and WAS is on `http://192.168.12.34:12345` (all ports/hosts fake), then my redirect comes back as `http://myserver.com` - correct host and port but wrong protocol.

How does WebSphere figure out the right host/port to use but not the protocol?  How can I force the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Apache mod_headers to add a custom header before the request is forwarded to websphere, in websphere, set the httpsIndicatorHeader to that custom header, then websphere will know to switch to https

http://www.ibmconnections.org/wordpress/index.php/tag/was-ssl-http-https/
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frweb_custom_props.html