# Using apache httpd as ssl store front for Liberty profile

Tags: apache, ssl, websphere-liberty

I would like to use Apache httpd to serve the public site and to offload SSL processing

Here's the topology
Client Browser -> HTTPS -> Apache httpd 2.2 -> HTTP -> Libery 8.5.5.4

Any idea how to configure Apache and Liberty Profile for the above configuration?

Comment: This is related to the underlying application server and to apache, not mobilefirst, as such I've removed the worklight/mobilefirst mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following works for me:

1. In the Libery server, add the following Web Container Custom Properties “httpsIndicatorHeader” in server.xml

`<webContainer httpsIndicatorHeader="Front-End-Https"/>`

2. In the Apache Server, add the following custom header to the virtual host configuration:

`<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
  :
  :
  RequestHeader add Front-End-Https "httpsIndicatorHeader"
  :
  :
</VirtualHost>`

The following articles help me come out with the solution I need:

1. This article explains SSL offloading with Websphere:
   http://orebmann.blogspot.com/2013/01/ssl-offloading-with-websphere.html
2. This article highlight steps required: 
   [WebSphere, sendRedirect and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625603/websphere-sendredirect-and-https)

Answer (score 0):

In short, here are the required steps:

- Download from WebSphere for Developers - Installation manager, and WebSphere Plugin.
- Install IBM Installation Manager
- Install WebSphere Plugin for Apache
- Generate plugin configuration - `plugin-cfg.xml` file in Liberty - either via mbean (jconsole), or Eclipse and WebSphere Developer Tools
- Copy `plugin-cfg.xml` to your Apache/Plugin server.

Useful links:

- [Configuring a web server plug-in for the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_webserver_plugin.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-6&lang=en)
- [WebSphere for developers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/)

Comment: Looks like your are providing a solution for developer workstation. I am looking for a solution for test/production server.

Comment: @ChrisCheah This is solution for production, you just use your production WebSphere license instead of developers and download Plugin from Passport advantage not from developers site.